# Drupal 7 add a field to the search block form configuration

Tags: drupal

I want to build a module that adds an extra field on the search form block configuration page to store text that will be displayed as the HTML5 placeholder attribute. What hooks do I need to use and how do I modify just the search form block to have that extra texbox that then gets printed on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that finally worked, thanks for your help:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
  if (($form_id == 'block_admin_configure') && ($form['module']['#value'] == 'search')) {
    $form['settings']['theplaceholder'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield', 
      '#title' => t('Add placeholder text'), 
      '#default_value' => variable_get('theplaceholder'),
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#description' => 'Override the default placeholder',
      '#weight' => 2,
      '#access' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourmodule_submit_function';
  }

if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = variable_get('theplaceholder');
  }
}
function yourmodule_submit_function($delta = '', $edit = array()){  
    variable_set('theplaceholder', $edit['values']['theplaceholder']);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked out.  It looks like you did use the form_alter hook, a submit function and variable_get and variable_set after all...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following hook to modify any form:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

}
```

Insert your own module name and the form id of the form you're trying to change.  In your case it would be search-form or search-block-form for just the block.  Find out the id of the form you're trying to change by viewing the page's html source and getting the id from the  element.

In any case, once you've figured out the proper id to insert, start adding elements to the form:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['my_new_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => t('Just testing'),
    '#weight' => 10, 
  );
}
```

Load the form up to make sure your new label, field or whatever is showing up.

Did that work for you?

More documentation on this function is here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7

Comment: Thanks for your reply; that code adds the field on the front end, what I would like is a textbox on the configuration settings for the search block so that I can input the placeholder text, then make it output on the front end...

Comment: Oh, it's the same principal.  If there's already a search box configuration form, you can look at the source code to get that form's ID and place ITS id in the function name.  Just look for the <form> element in the html source code and grab that ID.  Did you try that?  You can use this same hook to alter any form.  Let me know if you manage to find the correct form ID...

Comment: Ok I tried that and doesn't render the textbox on block admin form:

Comment: Wait, got it finally working with:
if (($form_id == 'block_admin_configure') && ($form['module']['#value'] == 'search')) {
 $form['settings']['theplaceholder'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield', 
      '#title' => t('Add placeholder text'), 
      '#description' => 'Override the default placeholder',
);
}
Now I need to take that value and pass it to the front end, any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Use variable_set and variable_get: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7  Now you have my code up there that prints a value -- you can get the value you've stored with variable_get().  To set it, you'll need to do that in a submit function that goes along with your form though...